# Telnet, Emulator ...and other issues

Tags: .net, emulation, telnet, mainframe

I was assigned to maintain a .NET application that use .NET emulator to connect to legacy mainframe system.
The application uses library called PowerTCP emulator.
But I see people use Putty to connect.
I hear lots of terms that I cannot make sense off, because I have no knowledge at all about mainframe / emulator / telnet world.
Like I hear the terms (VT100, VT320...) and I have no idea what they are

Is there something on internet that describe the ABCs for connection with emulator in .NET?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

VT100, VT320 and what not are terminal types.  There's not much to it.  They support different feature sets.  http://vt100.net/vt_history

I saw there was sample projects on the following site:

http://www.dart.com/ptemnet_samples.aspx

That might help.  What kind of work are you doing to "maintain" these apps?  Bugfixes or enhancements?

Comment: Thanks for reply
I am doing both bug fixes, and enhancements.

Comment: @user109534, sounds fun actually.  Sounds much more exciting than the boring boring stuff (reporting) I have been up to lately.